# numberOfLines TextInput property not working

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I have created an application in `react-native` and I have an option to chat in messages option. when I click inside TextInput and type two lines, the upper line gets hidden. To fix this I saw in the docs [numberOfLines](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#numberoflines) property but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```
<TextInput

                ref='textInput'
                multiline={true}
                numberOfLines: {5}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                style={[styles.textInput, {height: context.props.textInputHeight}]}
                placeholder={context.props.placeholder}
                placeholderTextColor="#5A5A5A"
                value={context.state.text}/>
```

I tried it in `getDefaultProps` function too:

```
getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      placeholder: 'Type a message...',
      navHeight: 70,
      textInputHeight: 44,
      numberOfLines:5,
      maxHeight: Screen.height,
    };
  },
```

But did not worked.

Answer (score 26):

To resume:

```
<TextInput
  ...
  numberOfLines={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? null : numberOfLines}
  minHeight={(Platform.OS === 'ios' && numberOfLines) ? (20 * numberOfLines) : null}
/>
```

Comment: What exactly does the number 20 indicate?

Comment: @kojow7 it's a height for each line

Comment: hardcoding 20 for each line is absolutely incorrect. On Android numberOfLines calculates automatically how much height is necessary for each line thus the textinput looks perfect

Answer (score 5):

You can use `maxHeight` and `minHeight` to accept what you want. For standard text fontSize, giving `maxHeight={60}` will make TextInput scrollable after 3 lines. This is good for IOS - for Android you can use `numberOfLines` prop.

Comment: yes now a days we can use maxHeight property but at that time when I asked this questions more than 2 years ago, it was not there in the docs. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2):

You have `numberOfLines: {5}`, should be `numberOfLines={5}`. Or is that just a typo only in SO?

In addition, styling `textAlignVertical: 'top'` is also recommended.

Comment: It works when I remove the height in style `style={[styles.textInput, {height: context.props.textInputHeight}]}` and If I add `textAlignVertical: 'top'` it does not display the text I write in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You should set `maxHeight`. I did set my `maxHeight={70}`.